# MS SQL Server CDC Cleanup Job to History Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, cdc, change-data-capture

I have a DB that has CDC enabled. Let's take a simple customer table for example.

**dbo.Customer**

You enable cdc on this table and get:

**cdc.Customer_CT**

SQL Server Agent will run the capture and cleanup jobs and you can set the parameters.

```
sys.sp_cdc_cleanup_change_table   
[ @capture_instance = ] 'capture_instance',   
[ @low_water_mark = ] low_water_mark ,  
[ @threshold = ]'delete threshold'
```

I however only want to keep a small amount of data within the _CT and move the rest to a history table that will be accessed less frequently.

That means we will also need:

**cdc.Customer_CT_History**

I am curious how I can configure the CDC cleanup job to delete the records from **cdc.Customer_CT** and insert them into **cdc.Customer_CT_History.**

I understand that this may not be the best approach to storing historical data but can you please just try and address my question and how I can accomplish this. Thanks!

Comment: Have you googled a Trigger for delete?

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.

CDC was originally conceived as a means to facilitate ETL by noting what changed on a given table. That said, there's nothing that keeps you from processing the CDC data with an ETL yourself and shoving it more or less unprocessed into a table of your own devising.

Answer (score 0):

When processing the data, make sure you address and use the __$update_mask column, as this will provide with exactly which columns have changed, to save you comparing across all columns. Also, you can use the __$start_lsn as a timestamp for the change being captured.